# VBA Error Handling not working in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have not had much experience with VBA, but I sometimes use it at work. Recently, I have encountered a problem that shouldn't happen, and that neither my boss nor myself can figure out.

Basically, the issue is that the `Application` property `DisplayAlerts` is set to `True` by default and can't be changed for some reason. Possibly related is that when I hit an error, it always display the End|Debug|Help alert and never hits the applied error handling.

I am running 64-bit Office 2010 on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine. However, I do not believe it to be a platform issue, as I have tested on multiple different platforms, operating systems and software permutations and no other machine has this error; just mine.

I have created some sample code in case anyone has encountered this before or has any ideas. The only thing I can think of, is that I have something installed on my machine that is causing this. But after a program purge and many restarts, I am no closer to deciphering what it might be.

```
Public Sub TestErrorHandler()

    ' Suppress alerts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim strArray(1) As String
    strArray(0) = "Hello"
    strArray(1) = "World"

    ' Set up error handler
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    For i = 0 To 3
        MsgBox strArray(i)
    Next

    ' Strip the error handler
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Unsuppress alerts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Exit Sub

    ErrHandler:

    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Description

    Resume Next

End Sub
```

The error is thrown on the third enumeration of the `for-loop` (as it should). The type of the error is irrelevant, what is relevant is that I get the error and never hit the error handler.

Any suggestions or help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Press <kbd>ALT + F11</kbd> from within Excel to reach VBA editor.

Goto Tools menu -> Options item -> General tab.

Set the error trapping to "Break on unhandled errors"

[image]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Aa155729.vba200111pa_f_image004(en-us,office.10).jpg))</sub>

Comment: I remember that one, took me a while to figure it out too.

Comment: Thank you very much! I knew it was something funny that I was overlooking. That worked perfectly! Many thanks :-D