# on error goto [label] not working in VBA

Tags: error-handling, excel, onerror, vba

In one of my Excel workbooks I have created a macro containing the following lines:

```
On Error GoTo saltaw
Open fileout For Output As #iFileNumber
```

However, when `fileout` contains some invalid chars ("\", for example) the macro stops and the error window "Runtime error '76': Path not found" appears, as if the `on error goto` line does not exist. Same if I substitute `on error goto` by `on error resume next`. The macro stops at the following line. Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VBA Error Handling not working in Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440735/vba-error-handling-not-working-in-excel)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA Error Handling not working in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440735/vba-error-handling-not-working-in-excel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Tools -> Options -> General` and set `Error Trapping` to something else that better suits you.

Comment: Ah, [found it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440735/vba-error-handling-not-working-in-excel) finally. I knew I had seen it before.