# Excel VBA Runtime Error '424' Object Required when deleting rows

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to compare cell values between 2 Sheets (Sheet1 & Sheet2) to see if they match, and if they match move the matching values in Sheet1 to a pre-existing list (Sheet3) and delete the values in Sheet1 afterwards.

I'm using the reverse For Loop in Excel VBA, but everything works until the part where I start deleting the row using `newrange1.EntireRow.Delete`.

This throws a '424' Object Required Error in VBA and I've spent hours trying to solve this, I'm not sure why this is appearing. Am I selecting the row incorrectly? The object?

Would appreciate if anyone can point me to the correct direction.

Here's my code:

```
Sub Step2()

    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

    Dim counter As Long, unsubListCount As Long, z As Long, x As Long, startRow As Long
    counter = 0
    startRow = 2
    z = 0
    x = 0

    ' Count Sheet3 Entries
    unsubListCount = Worksheets("Sheet3").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range, newrange1 As Range

    ' Select all emails in Sheet1 and Sheet2 (exclude first row)
    Set rng1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:D" & Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count)
    Set rng2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D1:D" & Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count)

   ' Brute Loop through each Sheet1 row to check with Sheet2
    For z = rng1.Count To startRow Step -1
        'Cells(z, 4)
        Set cell1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(z, "D")
        For x = rng2.Count To startRow Step -1
            Set cell2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(x, "D")

            If cell1.Value = cell2.Value Then ' If rng1 and rng2 emails match
                counter = counter + 1
                Set newrange1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(cell1.Row)

                newrange1.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & unsubListCount + counter)
                newrange1.EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

[image: 424 Object Required]

Comment: Looks fine to me. What does `newrange1` contain in the locals window?

Comment: its b/c newrange1 is assigned to Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(cell1.Row). It might be easy to get active cell's row? a = ActiveCell.Row

Comment: @GSerg what's a locals window? I'm quite new to VBA, i must add... 1 day old, :P

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem with the following short sub: `Dim newrange1 As Range, cell1 As Range :
Set cell1 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("a1") :
Set newrange1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(cell1.Row) :
newrange1.EntireRow.Delete` But that works fine (no errors). Do you have the sheet protected?

Comment: @KyleYeo https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264148.aspx

Comment: Is that code the actual code you are running? It feels like your actual code has either more or less parentheses.

Comment: a) Your inner loop produces a lot of unnecessary work. Better with `Application.Match`.

Comment: @DougCoats that's the thing I want to avoid the macro running on the active sheet, so i'm redirecting it to the correct sheet -- am I not supposed to do it this way?

Comment: @GSerg yes it is -- the ones I commented out are Msgbox statements for debugging.

Comment: @Ralph no it isn't protected -- just double-checked.

Comment: @DougCoats Please see http://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/11683. The OP is correct in using object references as opposed to `ActiveCell`.

Comment: Yes it def more preferred to reference what the current state of the loop is and then find the current row off of that.

Comment: @KyleYeo Are you sure that is [in fact](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4113134/11683) the line where the error occurs?

Comment: Just an idea because I once had a somewhat related problem: insert new lines of code such as `Set cell1 = Nothing` and `Set newrange1 = Nothing` **before** re-assigning them to new ranges (maybe at the end of the loops just before the ...next...).

Comment: @GSerg ok using your post I set it to break on all errors -- now I'm getting this as the highlighted sentence when I click on Debug: `If cell1.Value = cell2.Value Then ' If rng1 and rng2 emails match` -- does this mean this is the issue?

Comment: Could be to do with `Set rng1 = Worksheets("Sheet1 ")` <- There's an additional space in this sheet name.

Comment: @Jordan I rectified that -- the original one had no spaces there.

Comment: @GSerg the weird thing is, if I don't add the `.EntireRow.Delete` functionality, the entire script runs without any issues, so I thought this would be the function. I ran the debug again with the tools you provided but without the `.EntireRow.Delete` section again it goes smooth and doesn't throw anything up.

Comment: Do you have events handlers, especially for `Worksheet_Changed`?

Comment: @GSerg Nope, apart from this `Sub` I only have 2 other functions -- 1 to delete empty rows, 1 to check against a cell value in Sheet1 and clear that cell value if it matches.

Comment: Try to add `Exit for` before `End If`.

Comment: @KyleYeo Then we're back to [the locals window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42650672/excel-vba-runtime-error-424-object-required-when-deleting-rows?noredirect=1#comment72427637_42650672). What does it contain before executing `.EntireRow.Delete`?

Comment: @GSerg yeah I opened the locals window up -- it contains a `Range/Range` Type before `.EntireRow.Delete` is executed. There are a lot of values in there though.

Comment: @KyleYeo Then add `cell1`, `cell2` and `newrange1` to the watch window instead ant watch only them. Also execute the code step by step by pressing F8.

Comment: ... and check `? newrange1.Address` in the immediate window just before you execute `.EntireRow.Delete`. https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/vba-immediate-window-excel/

Comment: @GSerg from what I see in debug I am able to delete 1 entry that matches before getting the '424' Object Required error. I'll look into the `cell1`, `cell2`, `newrange1` and `newrange1.Address` -- this watch window should help loads.

Comment: @GSerg @Ralph doing `Msgbox newrange1.Address` gives me "$13:$13". That's a valid address, right?

Comment: @GSerg @Ralph it seems @Ryan might have solved my issue -- I think that's pretty much it -- I need to set `newrange1` to `Nothing`, then reset `cell1` to the next cell. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what's happening is when you are deleting the row, you are losing the reference to the range `Cell1`. So I reset this after the deletion is done, and removed the reference to newRange1. Give this a shot, I have it working on my end. I also formatted the code slightly too.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Testing()

    Dim counter         As Long: counter = 0
    Dim z               As Long: z = 0
    Dim x               As Long: x = 0
    Dim startRow        As Long: startRow = 2
    Dim Sheet1          As Worksheet: Set Sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim Sheet2          As Worksheet: Set Sheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim Sheet3          As Worksheet: Set Sheet3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
    Dim rng1            As Range: Set rng1 = Sheet1.Range("D1:D" & Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
    Dim rng2            As Range: Set rng2 = Sheet2.Range("D1:D" & Sheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
    Dim unsubListCount  As Long: unsubListCount = Sheet3.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Dim cell1           As Range
    Dim cell2           As Range
    Dim newrange1       As Range

   ' Brute Loop through each Sheet1 row to check with Sheet2
    For z = rng1.Count To startRow Step -1
        Set cell1 = Sheet1.Cells(z, 4)
        For x = rng2.Count To startRow Step -1
            Set cell2 = Sheet2.Cells(x, 4)
            If cell1 = cell2 Then
                counter = counter + 1
                Set newrange1 = Sheet1.Rows(cell1.Row)
                newrange1.Copy Destination:=Sheet3.Range("A" & unsubListCount + counter)
                newrange1.EntireRow.Delete
                Set newrange1 = Nothing
                Set cell1 = Sheet1.Cells(z, 4)
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: To note, basically adding these 2 lines `Set newrange1 = Nothing` and `Set cell1 = Sheet1.Cells(z, 4)` after `newrange1.EntireRow.Delete` solved it. Thanks!

Comment: @KyleYeo I guess you missed my comments in that respect a while back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42650672/excel-vba-runtime-error-424-object-required-when-deleting-rows#comment72428204_42650672 Then we could have solved it a lot sooner. RyanWildry: Thanks for making a fully-fledged reply out of that.

Comment: @Ralph yeah I realized -- too many comments coming in at the same time...

Answer (score 5):

Your inner loop produces a lot of step-by-step work that is better accomplished with `Application.Match`. Your use of `.UsedRange` to retrieve the extents of the values in the D columns is better by looking for the last value from the bottom up.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Step2()

    Dim z As Long, startRow As Long
    Dim rng2 As Range, wk3 As Worksheet, chk As Variant

    startRow = 2
    z = 0
    Set wk3 = Worksheets("Sheet3")

    ' Select all emails in Sheet1 and Sheet2 (exclude first row)
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        Set rng2 = .Range(.Cells(2, "D"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
    End With

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For z = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row To startRow Step -1
            chk = Application.Match(.Cells(z, "D").Value2, rng2, 0)
            If Not IsError(chk) Then
                .Cells(z, "A").EntireRow.Copy _
                    Destination:=wk3.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                .Cells(z, "A").EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

As noted by [Ryan Wildry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4839827/ryan-wildry), your original problem was continuing the loop and comparing after deleting the row. This can be avoided by adding `Exit For` after `newrange1.EntireRow.Delete` to jump out of the inner loop once a match was found. I don't think you should 'reset cell1' as this may foul up the loop iteration.

Comment: Cheers -- I'll integrate this into my code. Thanks so much!