# Error Handler not working on "438 run time error"

Tags: vba, excel

I have a script that loops through the shapes in a sheet, grabs the image attributes into `picHeight` and `picWidth` variables:

```
  ws.Shapes(myImg.ID).Select

         With Selection

                killer = IsError(.ShapeRange.Height)

            If IsError(.ShapeRange.Height) = True Then
                GoTo badShape
            End If


            PicHeight = .ShapeRange.Height

            PicWidth = .ShapeRange.Width

        End With
```

Sometimes the shape is not a picture (there are charts and text boxes on the sheet as well) and VBA keeps throwing a "438 error" (*Object doesn't support this property or method*) even when adding `on error resume next` as well as the error handler I have above. The issue arises when the selection object doesn't have the `.shaperange.height` or `shaperange.width` properties.

It seems VBA is simply incapable of even handing off the code to the error handler, simply because the selection doesn't have the selected members.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440735/vba-error-handling-not-working-in-excel/3440789#3440789) and see if that helps with the error handling.

Comment: I've gotten hit with that before, unfortunately it's not the case this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need error handling if you just use the `.Height` & `.Width` property (instead of `.ShapeRange.Height` or `.SHapeRange.Width`
I just tested the following against a chart, rectangle, picture and Form label:

```
Sub Shapes()

Dim sh As Shape
Dim wa As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheet1

For Each sh In ws.Shapes

    Debug.Print sh.Name & ": " & sh.Height
    Debug.Print sh.Name & ": " & sh.Width

Next

End Sub
```

And got the following results:

```
Chart 1: 216
Chart 1: 360
Rectangle 2: 72
Rectangle 2: 72
Picture 3: 218
Picture 3: 379
Label21: 18
Label21: 72
```

So, your code can be simplified to:

```
With ws.Shapes(myImg.ID)

    PicHeight = .Height
    PicWidth = .Width

End With
```