# Macro for PPT - Move TextBox contents to Placeholder - Maintain links and lists

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have PPTs that are being generated via software that I have no control over.  Upon generation, the software puts all text into TextBoxes instead of my Placeholders.

I created a script to move the text from the TextBoxes into the placeholders and this works great; however, I am unable to maintain the links and the lists are always showing as Bulleted despite some being numbers.  Basically, if there is a link in the textbox, it should still be a link in the Placeholder.  FYI, this script also changes shape 3 on each slide into the Title Placeholder

How can I preserve the formatting when I am moving the text over?  I attempted to use pastespecial, but that still was only moving the text into the format of the placeholder.

```
Sub TextBoxFix()
   Dim osld As Slide, oshp As Shape, oTxR As TextRange, SlideIndex As Long, myCount As Integer, numShapesOnSlide As Integer
Dim tempBulletFormat As PowerPoint.PpBulletType
For Each osld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    myCount = 1

    With ActivePresentation
    'For Each oshp In osld.Shapes
    osld.CustomLayout = ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(2)
    For i = osld.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set oshp = osld.Shapes(i)
        If i = 3 Then
            osld.Shapes.Placeholders.Item(1).TextFrame.TextRange = oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters
            osld.Shapes.Placeholders.Item(1).Visible = msoTrue
            oshp.Delete
          ElseIf i > 3 And oshp.Type = msoTextBox Then
          oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.Copy
          osld.Shapes.Placeholders.Item(2).TextFrame.TextRange.InsertBefore(oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.TrimText).ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Type = oshp.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Type
                   oshp.Delete
           End If
    Next i
    End With
 Next osld
End Sub
```

Comment: If via `link` you mean hyperlink and you would like to add it to shape object, check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff746252.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used OpiesDad's code as a starting point, and made some minor modifications.  I was getting an error related to the GetArray function when textboxes didn't exist.  In addition, I modified the code to run on all slides of the PPT. I also had to make some modifications to the TextBoxFix Sub because the content was being deleted, but wasn't populating in my Placeholders.

See my updates below:

Reused Class Module - Hyper

Removed "On Error GoTo 0" from the Exists Function in hyperColl

Revised TextBoxFix below:

```
 Sub TextBoxFix()
 Dim shp As Shape
 Dim shp2 As Shape
 Dim oHl As Hyperlink
 Dim hypAddr As String
 Dim hypText As String
 Dim hypTextLen As Integer
 Dim hypTextStart As Integer
 Dim hypShape As Shape
 Dim hypCollection As hyperColl
 Dim newHyper As Hyper
 Dim hypArray() As Hyper
 Dim hypToAdd As Hyper
 Dim i As Long
 Dim j As Long
 Dim bolCopy As Boolean

 For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
 With ActivePresentation
 sld.CustomLayout = ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(2)

 Set hypCollection = New hyperColl 'Set the collection of arrays - 1 for each shape

 Set shp = sld.Shapes(1)

 For Each oHl In sld.Hyperlinks

     If oHl.Type = msoHyperlinkRange Then 'Hyperlink is associated with part of a TextRange, not a whole shape
         hypAddr = oHl.Address
         hypText = oHl.TextToDisplay
         hypTextLen = Len(hypText)
         If TypeName(oHl.Parent.Parent) = "TextRange" Then
             hypTextStart = oHl.Parent.Parent.Start
             Set hypShape = oHl.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent
         End If
         Set newHyper = New Hyper
         newHyper.InitializeWithValues hypShape, hypTextStart, hypAddr, hypText
         hypCollection.Add_Item newHyper
     End If

 Next oHl
    For j = sld.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
     Set shp = sld.Shapes(j)
     bolCopy = False
     If j = 3 Then
         sld.Shapes.Placeholders.Item(1).TextFrame.TextRange = shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters
         sld.Shapes.Placeholders.Item(1).Visible = msoTrue
         shp.Delete

    ElseIf j > 3 And shp.Type = msoTextBox Then
      sld.Shapes.Placeholders.Item(2).TextFrame.TextRange.InsertBefore(shp.TextFrame.TextRange.TrimText).ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Type = shp.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Type
         If hypCollection.Exists(shp.Name) Then
              hypArray = hypCollection.GetArray(shp.Name)
              For i = LBound(hypArray) To UBound(hypArray)
                  Set hypToAdd = hypArray(i)
                 With sld.Shapes.Placeholders.Item(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(hypToAdd.getchrStart, Len(hypToAdd.getHypText)).ActionSettings.Item(1)
                       .Action = ppActionHyperlink
                       .Hyperlink.Address = hypToAdd.getHypAddr
                 End With
              Next i
         End If

       shp.Delete
    End If
 Next j
 End With
 Next sld

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This may have some formatting issues that need to be addressed, but this will insert the hyperlinks that you are looking for.  Code is likely not the cleanest, but it works.  You will also need to set the vba to break only on unhandled errors, or it will break in the middle of the code.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440735/vba-error-handling-not-working-in-excel/3440789#3440789).

Class Module - Hyper

```
 Private shp As Shape
 Private chrStart As Integer
 Private hypAddr As String
 Private hypText As String

 Private Sub Class_Initialize()

 End Sub

 Public Sub InitializeWithValues(newShp As Shape, newChrStart As Integer, newHypAddress As String, newHypText As String)

     Set shp = newShp
     chrStart = newChrStart
     hypAddr = newHypAddress
     hypText = newHypText

 End Sub
 Public Function getShape() As Shape

     Set getShape = shp

 End Function
 Public Function getchrStart() As Integer


     getchrStart = chrStart
 End Function

 Public Function getHypAddr() As String

     getHypAddr = hypAddr

 End Function

 Public Function getHypText() As String

     getHypText = hypText

 End Function
```

Class Module - hyperColl

```
 Private myCollection As Collection

 Private Sub Class_Initialize()

     Set myCollection = New Collection

  End Sub

  Public Sub Add_Item(newHyper As Hyper)

       Dim newArray() As Hyper
       If Me.Exists(newHyper.getShape().Name) Then
            newArray = myCollection(newHyper.getShape().Name)
            ReDim Preserve newArray(0 To UBound(newArray) + 1)
            Set newArray(UBound(newArray)) = newHyper
            myCollection.Remove (newHyper.getShape().Name)
            myCollection.Add newArray, newHyper.getShape().Name
       Else
            ReDim newArray(0)
            Set newArray(0) = newHyper
            myCollection.Add newArray, newHyper.getShape().Name
       End If



  End Sub
  Public Function GetArray(shapeName As String) As Hyper()

       GetArray = myCollection(shapeName)

  End Function

 Public Function Exists(shapeName As String) As Boolean
      Dim myHyper() As Hyper
      On Error Resume Next
      myHyper = myCollection(shapeName)
      On Error GoTo 0
      If Err.Number = 5 Then 'Not found in collection
          Exists = False
      Else
          Exists = True
      End If

      Err.Clear

  End Function
```

Regular Module (Call it whatever you want)

```
 Sub textBoxFix()

 Dim sld As Slide
 Dim shp As Shape
 Dim shp2 As Shape
 Dim oHl As Hyperlink
 Dim hypAddr As String
 Dim hypText As String
 Dim hypTextLen As Integer
 Dim hypTextStart As Integer
 Dim hypShape As Shape
 Dim hypCollection As hyperColl
 Dim newHyper As Hyper
 Dim hypArray() As Hyper
 Dim hypToAdd As Hyper
 Dim i As Long
 Dim j As Long
 Dim bolCopy As Boolean

 Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
 sld.CustomLayout = ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(2)

 Set hypCollection = New hyperColl 'Set the collection of arrays - 1 for each shape

 Set shp = sld.Shapes(1)

 For Each oHl In sld.Hyperlinks

     If oHl.Type = msoHyperlinkRange Then 'Hyperlink is associated with part of a TextRange, not a whole shape
         hypAddr = oHl.Address
         hypText = oHl.TextToDisplay
         hypTextLen = Len(hypText)
         If TypeName(oHl.Parent.Parent) = "TextRange" Then
             hypTextStart = oHl.Parent.Parent.start
             Set hypShape = oHl.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent
         End If
         Set newHyper = New Hyper
         newHyper.InitializeWithValues hypShape, hypTextStart, hypAddr, hypText
         hypCollection.Add_Item newHyper
     End If

 Next oHl
For j = sld.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
     Set shp = sld.Shapes(j)
     bolCopy = False
     If j = 3 Then
         Set shp2 = sld.Shapes.Placeholders.Item(1)
         bolCopy = True
    ElseIf j > 3 And shp.Type = msoTextBox Then
         Set shp2 = sld.Shapes.Placeholders.Item(2)
         bolCopy = True
    End If
    If bolCopy = True Then
         shp2.TextFrame.TextRange.InsertBefore(shp.TextFrame.TextRange.TrimText).ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Type =  shp.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Type
         If hypCollection.Exists(shp.Name) Then
              hypArray = hypCollection.GetArray(shp.Name)
              For i = LBound(hypArray) To UBound(hypArray)
                  Set hypToAdd = hypArray(i)
                  With shp2.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(hypToAdd.getchrStart, Len(hypToAdd.getHypText)).ActionSettings.Item(1)
                       .Action = ppActionHyperlink
                       .Hyperlink.Address = hypToAdd.getHypAddr
                  End With
              Next i
         End If
      End If
      shp.Delete
 Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks!  This gave me a great start.  It didn't work directly out of the box for me, but with some minor modifications it worked perfect.  See my answer with revisions